# Overwrite default selinux fcontext rules

Tags: centos7, selinux

I'm trying to overwrite default rule for public_html directory:

```
/home/[^/]*/((www)|(web)|(public_html))(/.+)?   unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0
```

Assigning the httpd_user_**rw**_content_t context

I tried to add another rule for the same path with:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_user_rw_content_t "/home/[^/]*/((www)|(web)|(public_html))(/.+)?"
```

But `restorecon -R /home/user/public_html` still assign httpd_user_content_t context.

Is there a way to overwrite the default rule? (Edit file_contexts.homedirs doesn't looks a good idea...)

Comment: You could try: `chcon -R -t httpd_user_rw_content_t /home/user/public_html` and let me know.

Comment: Yes, i can, but i want make it system-wide...

Comment: I think that's a terrible idea security wise but `chcon -R -t httpd_user_rw_content_t /` should achieve it.

Comment: I think chcon all the filesystem is a terrible idea because produce an unusable system... For system wide i mean that work as default setting for new files under all public_html folder in all homes...

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I understand better now. I believe what you are looking for is here: `etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/`  you can define rulesets for what context to apply to what files in what pattern. This is not something i have huge experience of tho.